# unable to insert record through jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Right now I am facing a problem : I am trying to insert records in the database with the help of `jQuery & Ajax`. Unfortunately, I tried to alert inserted values but It doesn't show. I also checked through serialize function and I am unable to do that.

Here is my code of ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#add_new").click(function(){
         $("#add").slideToggle();
      });

      $("#submit").click(function(){
         var stud_no=$("#roll").val();             
         if(stud_no==''){
            $("#msg").html("Input Roll Number");
         } else {
         var datastr = $("#sampleform").serialize();
         alert(datastr);
         $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'add_it.php',
            data:datastr,
            success:function(response){
               $("#my_form")[0].reset();
               $("#msg").html("Student Successfully Added");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            }
         });
         }

      });
   });
</script>
```

Here is body code :

```
<body>
<a id="add_new">+add new item</a><br /><br />
<div id="msg"></div><br />
<div id="add">
<form id="sampleform">


<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="roll" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Roll Number</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="roll" class="form-control" id="roll">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="clas" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Class</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" name="standard" class="form-control" id="standard">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="mail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control" id="mail">
      </div>
    </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
    </fieldset>

  </fieldset>
</form>
    </div>
```

Here is my add_it.php

```
<?php
include('connectdb.php');

$stud_no = trim($_POST['stud_no']);
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$standard = trim($_POST['standard']);
$mail = trim($_POST['mail']);

$query = "insert into student (stud_no,name,standard,email) values ('$stud_no','$name','$standard','$mail')";
mysqli_query($con,$query) or die (mysqli_error());      
?>
```

Comment: any errors in browser console?

Comment: Your code calls `mysqli_query()`, but then `mysql_error()` (without the "i"). This may produce an error if something goes wrong, depending on the version of PHP you are running.

Comment: Also, something that may be useful for you: you can use `print_r()` to print an array and see its contents. For example `print_r($_POST);` would have shown you that no POST variables are submitted through your form.

Comment: There is no stud_no input in the form.. I think that will be roll... Get stud_no like this .. $stud_no = trim($_POST['roll']);

Comment: I have update but still no luck

Comment: Then echo the Query variable and see what you got ? And paste it here as well

Comment: after some of troubleshoot i successfully insert the values in database but success message didn't display. as well as all values add in URL(like GET) even i used POST

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML form fields doesnt have any of these variables sent. You need to add name="email" etc to your form fields.

So for example the email field has to look like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="mail">
```

id, class etc is not sent in POST - and therefor can not be recieved in the other end.

Jquery's serialize() function also only handles "name" fields.

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Snippet :

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute